# How to access or detect a length of object/s in openCV?

Tags: image, object, opencv, detect

I am just new to openCV(3 days old) and currently creating a project that should assign different amounts of time for different lengths detected.

I was just wondering if there's a way to analyze or to run though the Y-axis of an image and then detect the presence(first binary 1 detected) and the end of an object or end of the length( last binary 1 detected after 0). I am having a hard time coding such using openCV since I don't know how openCV assigns X and Y axis in the digital image.

here is the picture
[binaryimage](http://i149.photobucket.com/albums/s48/vash1102/guide%20dota%20playing%20in%20rgc/withoutMask_zpsdbf21e7a.png?t=1390721393)

Is there a way to know the area? or length of such objects?

Comment: Please show an example/image.

Answer (score 1):

To assign a pixel value for a `cv::Mat` image:

- For grayscale image (`8UC1`)

  ```
  img.at<uchar>(y, x) = (uchar) value;
  ```
- For Color image (`BGR` style)

  ```
  img.at<Vec3b>(y, x) = Vec3b(blueValue, greenValue, redValue);
  ```

Comment: @herohuyoungtao thanks for taking the time, I was wondering if there was a much easier way to know certain areas in a binary image

Comment: No. There is no much easier way.